# How to prevent mixed data between respondents from Google Web App forms in Spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Google Web App to Spreadsheet integration and I wanted to write a data from my Google Web App forms to Spreadsheet instantly. Because when I try to submit my Web App forms at the same time from more than 1 link, the data result in the Spreadsheet get messed up between respondents because it needs time to write it one by one.

Here's my code:

```
function processForm(formObject) {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F2s-qjrUnafkJ4ueTbZPZPiVdKr66IZ6v4yF9DEt4wk/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");

  ws.appendRow([formObject.nama, formObject.npk, formObject.things1, formObject.weight1, formObject.target1]);
  ws.appendRow([null, null, formObject.things2, formObject.weight2, formObject.target2]);
  ws.appendRow([null, null, formObject.things3, formObject.weight3, formObject.target3]);
  ws.appendRow([null, null, formObject.things4, formObject.weight4, formObject.target4]);
  ws.appendRow([null, null, formObject.things5, formObject.weight5, formObject.target5]);
}
```

How to prevent all the data not mixed between respondents?

Comment: ```LockService```

Comment: Can you provide more information on your script? Using the method [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) returns the position of the last row that has content.

Comment: @Kessy thank you for the respond. I updated my code above, how can i use getLastRow() on the function?

Comment: @TheMaster thank you for the respond! I'm going to search around how to apply LockService to a forms

Comment: Have you tried something, if so, can you update the code and question?